# Unexplained error when running dart2js.bat

Tags: dart

Attempting to generate JavaScript from my Dart application yields the following message and no JavaScript:

```
--- Jun 21, 2013 9:50:51 PM Running dart2js... ---
C:\Program Files (x86)\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\dart2js.bat --suppress-warnings 
--out=C:\Users\nledon\dart\UnityPlayer\web\unityplayer.dart.js 
C:\Users\nledon\dart\UnityPlayer\web\unityplayer.dart\Dart\dart-sdk\" was unexpected at this time.
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Thanks.

**dart2js.bat**

```
@echo off
REM Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
REM for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
REM BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

setlocal
rem Handle the case where dart-sdk/bin has been symlinked to.
set DIR_NAME_WITH_SLASH=%~dp0
set DIR_NAME=%DIR_NAME_WITH_SLASH:~0,-1%%
call :follow_links "%DIR_NAME%", RETURNED_BIN_DIR
rem Get rid of surrounding quotes.
for %%i in ("%RETURNED_BIN_DIR%") do set BIN_DIR=%%~fi

rem Get absolute full name for SDK_DIR.
for %%i in ("%BIN_DIR%\..\") do set SDK_DIR=%%~fi

rem Remove trailing backslash if there is one
IF %SDK_DIR:~-1%==\ set SDK_DIR=%SDK_DIR:~0,-1%

set DART2JS=%SDK_DIR%\lib\_internal\compiler\implementation\dart2js.dart
set DART=%BIN_DIR%\dart
set SNAPSHOT=%BIN_DIR%\snapshots\utils_wrapper.dart.snapshot

set EXTRA_OPTIONS=
set EXTRA_VM_OPTIONS=

if _%DART2JS_DEVELOPER_MODE%_ == _1_ (
  set EXTRA_VM_OPTIONS=%EXTRA_VM_OPTIONS% --checked
)

if exist "%SNAPSHOT%" (
  set EXTRA_OPTIONS=%EXTRA_OPTIONS% "--library-root=%SDK_DIR%"
)

rem See comments regarding options below in dart2js shell script.
set EXTRA_VM_OPTIONS=%EXTRA_VM_OPTIONS% --heap_growth_rate=512

if exist "%SNAPSHOT%" (
  "%DART%" %EXTRA_VM_OPTIONS% "%SNAPSHOT%" "dart2js" %EXTRA_OPTIONS% %*
) else (
  "%DART%" %EXTRA_VM_OPTIONS% "%DART2JS%" %EXTRA_OPTIONS% %*
)

endlocal

exit /b %errorlevel%

:follow_links
setlocal
for %%i in (%1) do set result=%%~fi
set current=
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%i in ('dir /a:l ^"%~dp1^" 2^>nul ^
                                     ^| find ">     %~n1 ["') do (
  set current=%%i
)
if not "%current%"=="" call :follow_links "%current%", result
endlocal & set %~2=%result%
goto :eof

:end
```

**Dart Version & OS:**

Dart Editor version 0.6.17_r26023

Dart SDK version 0.6.17.2_r26023

Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: What is the command you are running?

Comment: @Fox32, I did this via GUI from the Dart Editor: Tools > Generate JavaScript.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: @SethLadd This was on Windows7.

Comment: Hm, not sure. You can try asking on compiler-dev@dartlang.org or filing a bug. Be sure to include the exact version of Dart Editor. Sorry for the troubles!

Comment: @SethLadd No worries. I'll be sure to file a bug thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your `dart2js.bat`?

Comment: @KaiSellgren Sure thing. I added it at the bottom, thanks.

Comment: I had the same error "was unexpected at this time." few weeks ago.  So, I installed my Dart SDK directly on "C:\dart-sdk\", added it to my windows PATH, and now : `dart2js -o./release/prj.js ./prj/web/prj.dart` work just fine.  Not sure if it's the same problem.  I suspected the path `Program Files (x86)` to be a part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by moving my dart editor installation to **C:\Program Files**

The Dart Editor doesn't seem to understand the **C:\Program Files (x86)** path.

Filed Issue #12452: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12452&thanks=12452&ts=1376491330